# I need help to create an algorithm to return a list of possible groups of numbers from a list of numbers

Tags: algorithm, search, combinations

One of the parts of a search algorithm I need to develop consists of a function that receives a list of integers and returns a list of list of integers based on some rules, here are the specifications.

The input list can have any amount of numbers varying from a min and max pre-determined values. The function needs to return all possible combinations of the input numbers that are sequencial and has a size that is 3 or greater.

The order of the ouput groups is not important.

As an example:

```
min = 1;
max = 10;

input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]

output = [ [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8] ]
```

The trick part is that the input list can receive any number of joker characters. Theses jokers can assume any value within the min and max values.

An example using jokers:

```
min = 1;
max = 10;

input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, J]

output = [ 
    [1, 2, 3], 
    [2, 3, 4], 
    [1, 2, 3, 4], 
    [6, 7, 8], 
    [1, 2, 3, 4, J, 6, 7, 8], 
    [2, 3, 4, J, 6, 7, 8], 
    [3, 4, J, 6, 7, 8],
    [4, J, 6, 7, 8], 
    [J, 6, 7, 8], 
    [6, 7, 8, J], 
    [7, 8, J],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, J, 6, 7], 
    [1, 2, 3, 4, J, 6], 
    [1, 2, 3, 4, J, 6], 
    [1, 2, 3, 4, J] 
]
```

When working with any possible number of jokers in the input I cannot come up with any algorithm that can solve this problem.

Are there any suggestions or pseudo code you could share to help me with this problem?

Comment: So that I got it correctly:

Min and max defines the integer boundary?

So if we use your above min and max but with differen integer list:
[0,1,3,5,11]

0 and 11 would not be included in the subset of solutions?

Comment: Why is J include in a solution when min and max are only defined in terms of integers

Comment: You can generate all sequences of the form [i, i + 1, i + 2, ..., i + k] with k >= 2 and min <= i <= max - k (_i.e._ generate all sequences of consecutive numbers, with length at least 3, in the [min, max] interval), and then check, for each such sequence, whether the number of required Jokers is greater than the number of available Jokers.

Comment: @nmanh You are right, but to be honest the input list would not be generated with numbers outside the min and max values

Comment: @mitchel-paulin min and max limits which values J can assume

Comment: In which language do you need this though? Also, the time complexity would be exponential to get the desired result. How large can a list be?

Comment: @vivek_23 max won't be greater than 15 and I am using C#

Comment: @sevontheedge, if there are multiple jokers in the list, can we assign all of them to same value?

Comment: @sevontheedge ok, sorry I ain't a C# dev.

Comment: What is the complete expected output for `min = 1; max = 10; input = [J, J, J]`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursion that may need tweaking depending on your needs. The idea is to enumerate to each possible ending point from each possible starting point. Jokers are only used for numbers not in the list. Since the list can be sparse, one way is to treat each number as a node in a graph, performing a search on still unseen starting points.

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(A, jokerMin, jokerMax, globalMin, globalMax, minSeqLen){
  // Record available elements
  let sansJokers = A.filter(x => x != 'J');
  let numbers = new Set(sansJokers);
  let numJokers = A.length - sansJokers.length;
  let seen = new Set();
    
  // Given a starting point,
  // go as far as possible
  function g(js, n, comb){
    let result = comb.length >= minSeqLen ? [comb] : [];
    
    if (globalMin <= n && n <= globalMax){
      if (numbers.has(n)){
        return result.concat(
          g(js, n + 1, comb.slice().concat(n)));
          
      } else if (js && jokerMin <= n && n <= jokerMax){
        return result.concat(
          g(js - 1, n + 1, comb.slice().concat('J')));

      } else {
        return result;
      }
    
    } else {
      return result;
    }
  }
  
  let result = [];
  
  // Find starting points
  
  // If there are at least minSeqLen
  // jokers, we can start anywhere.
  // Otherwise, look only below
  // existing numbers since a pure
  // joker sequence will have to 
  // connect to a number to be valid
  if (numJokers >= minSeqLen){
    return ['Enough jokers to start anywhere'];
  
  } else {
    for (let n of numbers){
      // search lower
      let tempN = n - 1;
      
      while (!seen.has(tempN) &&
        !numbers.has(tempN) &&
        tempN >= globalMin &&
        tempN >= jokerMin){
        
        seen.add(tempN);
        result = result.concat(
          g(numJokers, tempN, []));
        tempN--;
      }
      
      seen.add(n);
      result = result.concat(
        g(numJokers, n, []));
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

var jokerMin = 1;
var jokerMax = 10;
var globalMin = 1;
var globalMax = 15;
var minSeqLen = 3;

var input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 'J', 'J']

let str = '';

for (let comb of f(input, jokerMin, jokerMax, globalMin, globalMax, minSeqLen))
  str += JSON.stringify(comb) + '\n';

console.log(str);
```